# How to get specific param from posted JSON in Gin?

Tags: json, go, go-gin

I need to get one param from posted json.
And I don't want to make struct for only this.
This is what I have tried

```
type NewTask struct {
    Price uint64 `json:"price"`
}

func (pc TaskController) Create(c *gin.Context) {

    var service Service
    if err := c.BindJSON(&service); err != nil {
        log.Println(err) // this works
    }

    var u NewTask
    if err := c.BindJSON(&u); err != nil {
        log.Println(err) // this return EOF error
    }

    fmt.Println(u.Price)
}
```

Requested Json data have many other fields including *price*

```
{
   ...other fields
   price: 30
}
```

But this don't work.I think its because I am binding twice, How can I success in binding multiple?

Thanks

Comment: could you please share the returned error of `ShouldBind`?

Comment: I have updated post

Comment: Thanks, I will test and let you know if I have found something

Comment: Are you trying to bind it multiple times?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use [`ShouldBindJSON`](https://godoc.org/github.com/gin-gonic/gin#Context.ShouldBindJSON). The `BindJSON` is reading the body, so we are at `EOF` if the context Body get read multiple times.

`ShouldBindJSON` stores the request body into the context, and reuse when it is called again.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ShouldBindBodyWith` to bind request body multiple times without issue.

Usage:

```
var service Service
if err := c.ShouldBindBodyWith(&service, binding.JSON); err != nil {
    log.Println(err) // this works
}

var u NewTask
if err := c.ShouldBindBodyWith(&u, binding.JSON); err != nil {
    log.Println(err) // this will also work
}
```

**Reference**: https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/gin-gonic/gin#Context.ShouldBindBodyWith

`ShouldBindBodyWith` is similar with `ShouldBindWith`, but it stores the request body into the context, and reuse when it is called again.

**NOTE**: This method reads the body before binding. So you should use ShouldBindWith for better `performance` if you need to call only once.